# Partial template specialization with mismatching `int` and `size_t` not compiling

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, partial-specialization

With reference to the following code

```
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
struct Wot;
template <int... ints>
struct Wot<std::index_sequence<ints...>> {};

int main() {
    assert(sizeof(Wot<std::index_sequence<1, 2, 3>>) == 1);
}
```

This works on clang but does not work on gcc, when I change the type of the partial specialization to accept `std::size_t` in the index sequence however it works.

Who is right?  Clang or gcc?

---

See this in action here https://wandbox.org/permlink/5YkuimK1pH3aKJT4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ template parameter and partial specialization : strong or weak typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920518/c-template-parameter-and-partial-specialization-strong-or-weak-typing)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

gcc is right. This is exactly [[temp.deduct.type]/18](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct.type-18):

> If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of `i` differs from the type of the corresponding template parameter of the template named by the enclosing *simple-template-id*, deduction fails. If `P` has a form that contains `[i]`, and if the type of `i` is not an integral type, deduction fails. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<int i> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<short s> void f(A<s>);
> void k1() {
>   A<1> a;
>   f(a);             // error: deduction fails for conversion from int to short
>   f<1>(a);          // OK
> }
>
> template<const short cs> class B { };
> template<short s> void g(B<s>);
> void k2() {
>   B<1> b;
>   g(b);             // OK: cv-qualifiers are ignored on template parameter types
> }
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

Mirroring the example and simplifying the original question:

```
template <class T> struct Wot { };

template <int... ints>
void foo(Wot<std::index_sequence<ints...>> ) { }

int main() {
    foo(Wot<std::index_sequence<1, 2, 3>>{}); // error
    foo<1, 2, 3>({}); // ok
}
```

I think this is clang bug [16279](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16279)